# What's wrong with the following FsCheck test

Tags: f#, fscheck

It's probably something very simple, but I'm new to FsCheck and not sure why the below raises the error it does ("Geneflect: type not handled System.Numerics.BigInteger")?

```
open System.Numerics

type NumericGenerator =
    /// Generating BigIntegers (though only in the regular integer range for now)
    static member BigInt() =
        { new Arbitrary<System.Numerics.BigInteger>() with
            override x.Generator =
                Arb.generate<int>
                |> Gen.map (fun i -> new BigInteger(i)) }


[<Property>]
let ``Simple test`` (b: BigInteger) =
    Arb.register<NumericGenerator> |> ignore
    b + 1I = 1I + b
```

This is using FsCheck with xUnit integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FsCheck is trying to generate a BigInteger before calling your test, because the Arb.register call is in your test method itself. It then tries to do that via reflection, which fails.

You can tell FsCheck about your custom arbitrary instance by adding it as a argument to your property.

```
[<Property(Arbitrary=[|typeof<NumericGenerator>|])>]
```

Also, you can add the ArbitraryAttribute to the test's enclosing module to register that arbitrary instance for all the properties in the module. See https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck/blob/master/tests/FsCheck.Test/Runner.fs for some examples.

One final tip - if you are generating a type that's easily converted to/from another already generated type, you can easily create a generate and a shrinker using the `Arb.convert` method. Something like:

```
Arb.Default.Int32() |> Arb.convert ...
```

shoud work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, but won't be able to do this until I'm back home from work. I did actually try doing the registration in the enclosing module, but that gave me an error too (will have to look at the exact text again to recall what), even when I tried it with the EvenInt type I found in the FsCheck documentation. Maybe I messed up though, if I didn't (or didn't do so in an to me obvious way), I'll report back

Comment: That can be a bit tricky because of static initialization issues in different modules etc. It all gets a bit hairy. The way I described (with Property or the Arbitrary attribute) is the recommended and reliable way.

Comment: Ok, I'll use that. Tks!